# Convert Array to String and back to Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have built a presenter class whose only job is to convert a given array into a string. I am test driving the solution, so I started with `"[nil, nil, nil]"` but each `nil` will eventually be replaced with letter. That functionality is being handled by another class.

I am trying now to build an interface whose only job is to convert that string back to an array. So I will need to convert e.g. `"[\"a\", \"b\", nil]"` back to `["a", "b", nil]`. But I am stuck.

For example, I'd like to convert

```
"[nil, nil, nil]"
```

to

```
 [nil, nil, nil]
```

How could I do it?

Comment: I think you're being downvoted because it's not clear how your input can vary. If the only thing you ever need to convert is `"[nil,nil,nil]"` then you don't need to convert it all - just type `[nil,nil,nil]`.

Comment: Where is this data coming from?

Comment: Where does the string come from? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: I have built a presenter class whose only job is to convert a given array into a string.  I am test driving the solution, so I started with [nil, nil, nil] but each nil will eventually be replaced with letter. That functionality is being handled by another class.  I asked the above question because I am building an interface whose only job is to convert that sting back to an array.  So I will need to convert "[\"a\", \"b\", nil]" back to ["a", "b", nil].

Comment: @user3245240 what you want is called serializing or marshalling an object, which is a pretty common problem. See my answer for some options on how you could use existing libraries for that.

Comment: Does any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 7):

Just use:

```
eval(string)

eval("[nil, nil, nil]")
```

***Caution:***

**This is a very insecure method and you have to use it only if you are completely sure that the string contains a SAFE array..**

Comment: This is very un-secure way to parse input, as it may contain un-expected data, which may be dangerous.

Comment: @p11y Sometimes you need to, but you better have a **very good** reason to.

Comment: Editing to add the disclaimer.

Comment: Uri Agassi, p11y, anyone who upvoted those comments, and anyone who downvoted this answer, **Give an alternative way of doing this without using eval**. If you cannot, then retract what you wrote/did.

Comment: Used this one.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice, be careful with the content of the array!. And mark it as solution if you please :)

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are producing the string yourself on one side, for example:

```
arr = [nil, nil, nil]
str = arr.inspect
#=> "[nil, nil, nil]"
```

Whereas I would advise you to serialize the array using a format such as JSON, YAML or Ruby's built in Marshalling library.

## JSON

```
require 'json'

arr = [nil, nil, nil]
str = JSON.dump(arr)
#=> "[null,null,null]"

JSON.load(str)
#=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

## YAML

```
require 'yaml'

arr = [nil, nil, nil]
str = YAML.dump(arr)
#=> "---\n- \n- \n- \n"

YAML.load(str)
#=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

## Marshal

```
arr = [nil, nil, nil]
str = Marshal.dump(arr)
#=> "\x04\b[\b000"

Marshal.load(str)
#=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: None of the three ways you suggest would solve the OP's problem. Notice that, even the closest YAML cannot handle `"[nil, nil, nil]"`; it requires a different string `"[null,null,null]"`.

Comment: @sawa Yes, my answer is only valid under the assumption that the OP controls the generation of the string as well. He just commented on his own question that this is the case, so I still think my answer is valid.

Comment: @sawa: OP has presented an X/Y problem, and actually wants to serialise/de-serialise data. I think p11y is correct. Question *should* ideally be re-written with current serialisation code, and "what now?" (I've had a try at that)

Comment: This is a far better answer than any which strictly adhere to the OP's narrow problem definition.

Comment: p11y, Neil Slater, Mark Thomas: The problem was terrible. I agree with that.

Comment: @sawa someone smart once called these questions ["presenting problems"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presenting_problem). The problem is simply that people often don't know what they are really looking for, so you have to make (a series of) guesses to come up with a really helpful solution. Anyway, let's move on :)